# How to pass different fetch requests to one view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

Currently I am having two identical views that serve different purposes: Earnings and Spendings. The main difference between the views is the data they handle. `EarningsView` handles a `Earning` entity and `SpendingsView` handles a `Spending` entity of CoreData.

My idea is to combine the views to one. This is a reduced version of how far I came:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            EarningsView().tabItem {
                    Text("Earnings")
            }.tag(1)
            SpendingsView().tabItem {
                    Text("Spendings")
            }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct SpendingView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Spending.date, ascending: true)]) var spendings: FetchedResults<Spending>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(spendings, id: \.self) { spending in
                Text(spending.name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Spendings"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let spending = Spending(context: self.viewContext)
                spending.name = "Foo"
                spending.date = Date()
                do {
                    try self.viewContext.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }) {
                Image(sytemName: "plus")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct EarningView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Earning.date, ascending: true)]) var earnings: FetchedResults<Earning>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(earnings, id: \.self) { earning in
                Text(spending.name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Earnings"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let earning = Earning(context: self.viewContext)
                earning.name = "Bar"
                earning.date = Date()
                do {
                    try self.viewContext.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }) {
                Image(sytemName: "plus")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The following code should replace the previous one:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Earning.date, ascending: true)]) var earnings: FetchedResults<Earning>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Spending.date, ascending: true)]) var spendings: FetchedResults<Spending>
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            CombinedView(data: earnings, tilte: "Earnings").tabItem {
                    Text("Earnings")
            }.tag(1)
            CombinedView(data: spendings, title: "Spendings").tabItem {
                    Text("Spendings")
            }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct CombinedView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data // Type ???
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.title))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                let newItem = ???(context: self.viewContext)
                newItem.name = "Bar"
                newItem.date = Date()
                do {
                    try self.viewContext.save()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }) {
                Image(sytemName: "plus")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fill my `CombinedView` with data correctly, so that the object in the view has the correct type and when I add a new object, it is added to the correct entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Earning` and `Spending` are almost the same.
You correctly tried to combine your views. Now you can try to combine models as well:

```
struct Transaction {
    var name: String
    var date: Date
    var type: TransactionType
}

enum TransactionType: String {
    case earning, spending
}
```

This is just an idea as in `CoreData` you need NSManagedObject *classes*.

Note that you can't store enums in `CoreData`. You can use `rawValue` for that.

In your new `ContentView` you can filter earnings and spendings:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [...], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", TransactionType.earning.rawValue)) 
    var earnings: FetchedResults<Transaction> // <- result type is now Transaction
    ...
}
```